# How to change 'timeout' of the UEFI boot manager from Windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, uefi

How can I change the 'timeout' setting of the EFI boot manager from within Windows 8? I am trying to dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu and I would like to be able to choose one or the other OS at boot time.

What tool can I use for that? Currently the timeout is 0sec, but I'd like to change it to 10sec. I already tried to use `sudo efibootmgr -t 10` from within Ubuntu, but that didn't work very well. And that's why I'm looking for a reliable Windows-based solution.

Comment: You can change this within the UEFI settings.  Spam the button for your motherboard after you use use the Advanced Boot menu.

Comment: try this tool: http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html